# graphic user interface in VBA - textbox save data

Tags: vba, user-interface, textbox, userform

I have created a user interface using userform. And a textbox has been used to let the users enter the inputs. 
I do not know how I can save the data from the userform. Inserted data is gone when I close and reopen the user interface. 
I have used the following code but it did not help in saving my inserted data. Sorry I am new to VBA.
I have to close the userform to run the model but it does not keep the inserted value!

```
Private Sub Other_Int_GUI_Change()
input = textbox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to define "save" if you want anyone to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only about saving the data, then you can simply write the input into the Excel Sheet:

```
Cells(1, 1) = input
```

Ps: All Variables will be reset once you close the UserForm. That means that the only way of keeping it, is to save it on the Sheet.
Not 100% sure, though.

Comment: I am looking for a way to save the data on the same UserForm and be able to see it after re-opening it. You mean that there is no way to do so?!

Comment: Yes, You can display the stuff you saved in the cells (in a Label)

`Label1.Caption = Cells(y, x)`

Don't know if that's excatly what you want.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you are trying to display when starting the UserForm again.  If it's the latest entry then you can save the last row & column in the Sheet (just pick a random place). With every entry you increase the row value  `Cells(y, x) = input`  `Cells(50, 50) = y`  `Cells(51, 50) = x`  When you save the next you just add +1 to x or y, however you like it. When starting the UserForm you can then use:  `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`  `x = Cells(51, 50)`  `y = Cells(50, 50)`  `Label1.Caption = Cells(y, x)`.

Comment: So, the same textbox that we used to insert the input should keep that number till we change it again. I do not want to write in textbox and print it on label. I just want to make the textbox last longer. Not to be removed once we closed it.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way of preventing the TextBox from behing cleared, you have to fill it automaticly once you reopen the UserForm.